# How to allow browsing to subdomain with different IP address - AWS

Tags: apache2, dns, aws

I have an AWS virtual machine, and it's running my CRM system fine. I want to set up a subdomain of my main website to go there instead - so I want www.crm.domain.co.nz to go to a different IP than just www.domain.co.nz

I have added the CRM server's IP address as an a-record of crm.domain.co.nz, but browsing to it gives "403 - forbidden" error, yet browsing to the IP address directly gives normal browsing

What am I doing wrong?

Server: AWS Hosted
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
CRM: SugarCRM

Thankful for any advice...

Comment: You use `apache` or `ngnix` or .... Different ip is on the same server or not?

Comment: Sorry. Apache, and on a different server instance

Comment: I need more information. You have two instances, instance A on private ip X and instance B on private ip Y and this instances are connected to router. Router have public ip and do forwarding port 80 to instance A or you have instance A on public ip and instance B on different public ip? I first scenario problem is forwarding of port 80. I second scenario problem is probably on apache configuration on instance B. Can you please explain topology?

Comment: Two public ip addresses, two separate server instances. I suspect the configuration on B, but don't see where to fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is on topic because it deals with DNS records which may or may not be managed by a DNS server that you control (and that runs Ubuntu). In any case you may find better answers over on [SF] or [Webmasters.SE].

Comment: Thanks David, I'm using Plesk on the same server so have all DNS on the machine in question. The issue was the below "<Directory> structure of conf Require all granted". So, it's on-topic of *allowing* browsing as in my question, but admittedly does go into SugarCRM a bit. The AWS bit I put on there because sometimes the permissions of AWS can cause issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check resolving on the PC from which you try to connect B. `host crm.domain.co.nz`. If you got the IP then is all ok.

Check virtual host directive in Apache.

For example, create a new Apache configuration file named `sugar.conf`:

```
touch /etc/apache2/sites-available/sugar.conf
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/sugar.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sugar.conf
vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/sugar.conf
```

then, add the following lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@your-domain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sugar/
   ServerName your-domain.com
   ServerAlias www.your-domain.com
   <Directory /var/www/html/sugar/>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/your-domain.com-error_log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/your-domain.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

You must change `your-domain.com` with you real domain.

Restart the Apache web server for the changes to take effect:

```
service apache2 restart
```

The following files and directories inside the `/var/www/html/sugar/` directory need to be writable from your web server:

```
'config.php' 
'config_override.php'
'sugarcrm.log'
'cache' and all subdirectories and files
'custom' and all subdirectories and files
'data' and all subdirectories and files
'modules' and all subdirectories and files
```

This can easily be accomplished by executing the following command:

```
chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/sugar/
```

I guess that you have configured `DB` for `sugar`.

Because you have "all" configured, maybe only you can check `DocumentRoot` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

```
grep -R "DocumentRoot" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

Output will be something like

```
sites-enabled/000-default.conf   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

If you do not have your `sugar DocumentRoot` in output you can change that.

Comment: OK, so I have both:    ` :/home/ubuntu# grep -R "DocumentRoot" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sugar.conf:   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/crm/    
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:    DocumentRoot /var/www/html    `

Comment: Ok. If you have `DocumentRoot` probably is error in configuration of `sugar.conf`. Add in <Directory> structure of conf  `Require all granted` behind `AllowOverride All` and restart `apache`

Comment: Yep! we're away. Much appreciated.